# Date convert to local timezone

Tags: android, android-studio

hello i am converting date by simple date format method but it returning wrong output time like  i need this

input:2016-06-28T08:19:05.721Z

output should be :13:49:05

but its returning :08:19:05

```
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        Date newDate = null;
        try {
            newDate = format.parse("2016-06-28T08:19:05.721Z");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String date = format.format(newDate);
```

Comment: Pass a locale to the formater

Comment: The input is 2016-06-28T08:19:05.721Z, why is the output be 13:49:05?

Comment: what do you want to do ? please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Use this constructor from `SimpleDateFormat` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a **Locale** to the SimpleDateFormat along with the pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        Date newDate = null;
        try {
            newDate = format.parse("2016-06-28T08:19:05.721Z");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        String date = format.format(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the parsing pattern

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

to

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
```

so that the input timezone is actually taken into account (and not just expecting a literal `Z`).

For formatting, your default timezone is used and assuming it's UTC+05:30, you'll get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = format.parse("2016-06-28T08:19:05.721Z");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String date = format.format(newDate);


    format .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date parsed = null; // => Date is in UTC now
    try {
        parsed = format .parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
    SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

    date = destFormat.format(parsed);
    Log.e("date",date);
```

i solved by doing this..Thanks all :)